# ComboBox placeholder not showing randomly

Tags: javafx, combobox, placeholder

I have a `ComboBox` that is shown every time you choose a specific item in another combo box.

I have a `Label` as a placeholder until the content of the combo box is loaded. It is supposed to be shown in the popup menu of the combo box. Most of the times, it works fine. But sometimes, like every fifth or tenth time, no placeholder is shown. Instead there's just a white cell until the content is loaded.

In the code below I managed to recreate the problem. It's not quite the same though. In my original code the white cell could happen at any time when I reloaded the combo box, but in my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it only occurs the first time the combo box is loaded (I'm almost certain).

So when you reproduce the problem, start the application and choose "bar" in the first combo box and check the placeholder, if it is normal, restart the application and try again. If have not been able to find any difference in first selecting "foo" and then "bar" or just selecting "bar" directly.

For the record I could not reproduce the issue without having the combo box shown only on specific choices in the first combo box, so that could cause the issue. But the design needs to be that way.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setPrefSize(200, 200);

        ComboBox<String> selector = new ComboBox<String>();
        selector.getItems().addAll("foo", "bar");

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();

        root.getChildren().add(selector);

        selector.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.equals("bar")) {
                root.getChildren().add(comboBox);
                comboBox.setEditable(true);

                 // Mock loading task.
                Task<List<String>> task = new Task<List<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<String> call() throws Exception {

                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        return Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");
                    }
                };

                task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
                    comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                            task.getValue());
                });

                Label loadLabel = new Label("loading");
                comboBox.setPlaceholder(loadLabel);

                task.stateProperty().addListener(
                        (o, oldState, newState) -> {
                            if (newState == State.RUNNING) {
                                // Do nothing in this MVCE.
                            } else {
                                comboBox.setPlaceholder(null);
                            }
                        });

                new Thread(task).start();

            } else {
                if (root.getChildren().contains(comboBox)) {
                    // This is done to simulate the functionality of the real application, 
                    //where choosing another option would remove the combo box and show something else.
                    comboBox.getItems().clear();
                    root.getChildren().remove(comboBox);    
                }
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);      
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Another question: When content of the popup list is loaded, the list remains the size of the placeholder until you hide and show the popup list again. I want the popup to expand instantly. Is this possible?

Edit: Java version 1.8.0_60. OS: windows 8.1 Enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't see the "loading" label is due to the logic you implemented in the state listener on the task:

```
    Label loadLabel = new Label("loading");
    comboBox.setPlaceholder(loadLabel);

    task.stateProperty().addListener(
            (o, oldState, newState) -> {
                if (newState == State.RUNNING) {
                    // Do nothing in this MVCE.
                } else {
                    comboBox.setPlaceholder(null);
                }
            });

    new Thread(task).start();
```

According to the [Javadocs for `Worker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html), a `Task` will start in the `READY` state, then transition to the `SCHEDULED` state, before going to the `RUNNING` state. The state transition diagram looks something like:

[image]

So when it transitions from `READY` to `SCHEDULED`, your listener will set the placeholder to `null`, and will never change it back. Just change the listener to

```
    task.stateProperty().addListener(
            (o, oldState, newState) -> {
                if (newState == State.RUNNING) {
                    comboBox.setPlaceholder(loadLabel);
                } else {
                    comboBox.setPlaceholder(null);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thank you! Although on your answer it sounds like the problem should be constant, so why does it occur stochastically? And do you happen to know the answer to my second question while you're at it? :)

Comment: The transitions between states are determined by the background thread (though the actual updatesare happening on the FX Application Thread, of course), so the behavior depends on the timing between the different threads. I don't know a better solution to the second question that the one already posted.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the problem with the placeholder. What Java version are you using?

2nd part of the question.
To force the comboBox to redraw. Simply hide it before adding the items and then show it again if it was showing.

```
            task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
                boolean isShowing = false;
                if (comboBox.isShowing()) {
                     comboBox.hide();
                     isShowing = true;
                }
                comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                        task.getValue());
                if (isShowing) comboBox.show();
            });
```

Comment: Added java and OS version info to the original question.

Comment: And your solution to the second part of my question does solve the issue, but is it not particularly pretty. I would prefer a solution that handles it without compromising the design. But I appreciate the effort!